# Ideal twine for training hops

Tags: growing-hops

I'm looking around the internet and have found that some people use nylon twine, which I am guessing is better for strength and resistant to the sun, rain and snow... then others use wire, some use gardening twine.

I'm trying to determine the best type of training media for my hops.  I figure that nylon twine doesn't provide enough friction for the hops to train against but that's where this question comes from.

thank you in advance for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This my first year growing hops, I was under the impression that home hop growers are really just looking for something reasonably strong but cheap, since you'll likely just be cutting it away after the season.

So going too expensive is a waste of money since it'll unlikely be reusable, but just enough to have something strong and weather proof for the growing season so that the vine doesn't fall.

I went for some cheap yet pretty strong polypropylene rope from Home Depot, I think about a dollar per 10 feet. My vines are about 3 feet at this point and they seem to be happy with it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  It looks like this stuff is about 100 lb tensile strength, is that about reasonable?   I wonder what a 15-20ft hop bine weighs...

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Watching the whole video is a bet slow and tedious, but I learned a lot [from this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIia4q3_rSY&t=930). I time marked it a 15:30 where the guy who has been doing it for years literally is using just cheap baling twine. And I know someplace in the video he talks about how his first year he was scared and bought super nice rope and never did that again because he wasted too much money on something that wasn't needed. Good luck with grow!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a string-like twine and plastic-coated metal wire.

The plastic-coated metal wire is so much better. Stronger, and the hops are training themselves up them better without the need for manual intervention.

Comment: Do you keep your wire up all year?   Do you have trouble detaching the bines from the wire?

Comment: I restring each year, and it comes off perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine most cheap twine will work just fine. Jute or another cheap twine used for gardening should be doing fine. You will cut the vines down every year, so I wouldn't go for something expensive.

I can't imagine you would have more than 50lbs on one vine, so strength is probably not a huge concern.